# why this pointer value not printed?

Tags: c++

i have a code:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *a, y = 6 , *yPtr = &y;

    cout << "y:" << y << "| &y:" << &y << "| yptr:" << yPtr << "| *yptr:" << *yPtr << " | &yptr:" << &yPtr << " |a:" << a << endl;
    *a = y;
    cout<< "a:"<<a<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when i assign *a to y `*a = y` then *a value not printed for me

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.

Comment: use `a=&y;` instead of `*a = y;`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you never initialize `a` itself. `*a` points to who-knows-where, some random location. So you set some random location to 6.

As it's probably pointed outside of legal space, your program is probably quitting before it gets to the `cout` statement.